# Managing Multi-Tenancy Data Consumption with Spring Batch

Tags: spring, kubernetes, spring-batch, multi-tenant

I'm currently working on a system where I need to consume data from an upstream system via an internal object store for different tenants. The challenge I'm facing is that the data volume for each tenant varies significantly – some tenants may have around 100,000 records a day, while others might have up to 1 million records in a daily file.

As of now, I have a Spring Batch job that reads files from the object store. However, since we're moving towards a multi-tenancy model, I'd like to gather insights and experiences from the community on using Spring Batch for such scenarios.

Specifically, I'm interested in:

```
1. How have you managed multi-tenancy data consumption in Spring Batch?
2. Are there any design considerations or best practices to handle varying data volumes per tenant?
3. Are there specific strategies or configurations that worked well for you in terms of scalability and performance?
4. Any challenges or pitfalls to watch out for when running Spring applications in Dockerized containers on Kubernetes?
```

I'm running my Spring application in Dockerized containers on Kubernetes, so if there are container-specific considerations, I'd love to hear about them.

Any advice, tips, or experiences you could share would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!